# How to find how many numbers occur within a range in C++?

Tags: c++, range

I've written a program to produce a set of 10000 random numbers with a mean of 1000 and a standard Deviation of 100. This part of the program works.
What im struggling with is within those 10000 numbers i must find how many of them fall within the range of 500 and 1500. As you'll see with my code i attempted this with a while loop but it failed. It returns 0 numbers between a range of 500 and 1500.

```
#include <random>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<vector>  
using namespace std;

int main() {

int n = 10000;
int mean = 1000; 
float stdev = 100;
int maxNum = 1500;
int minNum = 500;
int count = 0;
int number;

int min = std::min(maxNum, minNum);
int max = std::max(maxNum, minNum);

default_random_engine randEng; 
randEng.seed(10);
normal_distribution<>normal(mean,stdev); 


 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        number = normal(randEng);
        count++;
    }

  if (number >= min && number <= max) {
  count++;
}

  if(count = 1) {
  std::cout << "There is " << count << " number between 500 and 1500 in the distriubtion" << std::endl;
  } else if (count > 1) {
    std::cout << "There are  " << count << " numbers between 500 and 1500 in the distriubtion" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std:cout << "There are no numbers between 500 and 1500" << std::endl;
  }

 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just accumulate that count during generation ? I.e. In the generation loop, `if (number >= min && number <= max) ++count;`, and throw out the while loop entirely. Btw, your generation loop is broken too. You're just generating randoms, not using the distribution at all. It should be using `number = normal(randEng);`

Comment: If you want to accumulate the counts after having generated the numbers, then store all the generated values in a container (like `std::vector<int>`).   Then you can use standard algorithms like `std::count_if()` to count the number of generated values that meet whatever criteria you wish.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried to use if and it returns 0.See my updated Question

Comment: That's because your generation of `number` is broken. See the second part of my comment. And again, that accumulation for `count` belongs **inside** the generator loop. Your code shows it outside, which means it will only check the *last* number generated.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes i changed this. I keep getting 1 as the only number. Im unsure if thats fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is wrong, and your failing to use your `normal_distribution` correctly (at all, actually).

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    int n = 10000;
    int mean = 1000;
    float stdev = 100;
    int maxNum = 1100;
    int minNum = 900;
    int count = 0;
    int number;

    int min = std::min(maxNum, minNum);
    int max = std::max(maxNum, minNum);

    std::default_random_engine randEng;
    randEng.seed(10);

    std::normal_distribution<>normal(mean, stdev);


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        number = static_cast<int>(normal(randEng));
        if (number >= min && number <= max)
            ++count;
    }

    std::cout << "There are " << count << " numbers between " << min << " and " << max << " in the distribution\n";

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
There are 6867 numbers between 900 and 1100 in the distribution
```

The wider you make that distribution, the more numbers will fall within. Note the usage of the distribution object on concert with  the generator:

```
number = static_cast<int>(normal(randEng));
```

And likewise note the accumulation of `count` is **inside** the generator loop, unlike your thrice-updated code that has it *outside* the loop, and thus executed only once.